# Intersection of lines in 3-D space.

Tags: vectors

I have a line $l$ that passes through the point $(3,2,-1)$ and am told that this line  intersects the two lines with parametric representations:

$(x,y,z)=(1+t, t, -5+t)$ and $(x,y,z)=(10+5t, 5+t, 2+2t)$

I need to find a parametric representation of the line $l$.

I let the point $(3,2,-1)$ be $O$ and the points of intersection of $l$ and the other two lines be $P(1+t, t, -5+t)$ and $Q(10+5t, 5+t, 2+2t)$, for some real $t$.
Then my argument was that if $l$ intersects these two lines, then the points $O,P,Q$ are collinear, which follows that the vectors $OP$ and $PQ$ are parallel. Then I went on to say, for some real $k$, $OP=kPQ$, and tried to solve for $t$, but this did not work. The $t$ I obtained did not produce consistency in $z$-coordinates, only in $x$ and $y$. What is the fault in my argument? What is a better approach?

Comment: Does it intersect the two lines at right angles? Otherwise I cannot see how you can make any progress. If it does interesect at right angles the the line direction (a, b, c) has dot product 0 with the two given line directions. You can also take a = 1 arbitrarily for a line direction.

Comment: The manner in which it intersects the two lines has not been specified, so I had to think that angles should be excluded in approaching the problem.

Comment: You can't index Q by t, you need another variable s. Then OP = kPQ will be three equations involving the variables t, s and k. Funnily enough, you couldn't get a unique solution in 2D but the extra room in 3D allows one for your given lines as they are not coplanar.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing and found the solution. Interesting point you made there, on there being extra room in 3-D allowing for uniqueness of solution. Thanks Paul.